# Google Maps Display multiple markers Android

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develop an android application that display markers representing all the trees around my area. Being new to Android Development, I am not sure how to retrieve the data from Json.  I am only able to display 1 tree, and its name.  What I want to accomplish is display all the trees along with their names.  Any help/suggestion would greatly appreciated.Below is the Json representation.

```
{"Tree_ID":"19",
"Tree_Name":"Freeman Maple",
"Latitudes":"41.60659790",
"Longitudes":"-88.07947396"},

{"Tree_ID":"20",
"Tree_Name":"Ginkgo ",
"Latitudes":"41.60653306",
"Longitudes":"-88.07937155"},

{"Tree_ID":"21",
"Tree_Name":"Golden Raintree",
"Latitudes":"41.60644056",
"Longitudes":"-88.07604981",},

{"Tree_ID":"22",
"Tree_Name":"Greenspire Linden",
"Latitudes":"41.60560806",
"Longitudes":"-88.08078320"},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from `JSON` like below.

```
    private class AsyncTaskGetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = your webservices goes here....
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dataObject = null;
                        try {
                            dataObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                            String str1 = dataObject.getString("Tree_ID");
                            String treename= dataObject.getString("Tree_Name");
                            String latitude = dataObject.getString("Latitudes");
                            String longitude = dataObject.getString("Longitudes");

                            // Call this method for draw marker in google map

                            drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)),treename);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

// And call this AsyncTask like below from onCreate() or onResume() or from where you want.

```
new AsyncTaskGetData().execute();
```

***Add that data in `ArrayList` and and use where you want.***

**For set multiple Markers in Map**

// This Method drawmarker in Google Map

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point,String text){

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(point).title(text).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
}
```